# What if you made the fine print of a contract too small to read?

Tags: united-states, contract-law

I was talking with a friend the other day and they asked me what would happen if you made the fine print of a legally binding contract too small to read? Would the person who signed it be able to sue you? Are there any laws against this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what would happen if you made the fine print of a legally binding contract too small to read?

The contents of unreadable fine print would be unenforceable. That is because it does not meet the tenet that parties enter the terms *knowingly*. Even if the draftsman alleges the counterparty "unreasonably" declined to ask for legible print, the fact-finder be unable to ascertain the parties' legal position pursuant to unreadable print. The rest of the contract is binding and enforceable.

> Would the person who signed it be able to sue you?

No. It would be pointless. The unreadable print is nothing but meaningless scratch/mark/sign that gives neither party a cause of action.